# How to convert only the numbers to int in a list that has numbers and char in Python

Tags: python, list

I am learning Python and while practicing, I have this type of input:

- 1 2 3 4 S
- 3 4 5 6 N
- 3 4 1 8 S

It will always be a set of numbers separeted by space and end with a letter (char).
I am reading it with input() and making it a list like this

```
data = input()
myList = data.split()
```

What I want is to take the list and put only the numbers to a new list.
I tried this, but it only works if the list only has int values:

```
myList = [int(i) for i in myList]
```

How can I only take the int values and put them in a new list.

NOTE: My data input always ends with a letter but it will be nice if I someone gives a solution where there are letters at any random index of the list. Thanks in advance

Comment: `myList = [int(i) for i in myList if i.isdigit()]` Will give you the numbers as `int`s with no letters

Comment: Note that `isdigit()` will not work for negative numbers because the sign is not a digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a filter to the comprehension.

```
msj = [int(i) for i in msg if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Wow, this was fast. Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! I'm really starting to get fond of this Python community

Comment: It's worth noting that `isdigit()` won't work on negative numbers (but that doesn't look like an issue here).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
new_list = []
for item in myList:
    if item.isdigit():
        new_list.append(int(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that the letter will always appear at the end of the string:

```
newList =  [int(n) for n in myList[:-1]]
```